# Split image and tag splits based on line in OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I have an image which can be split by a delineating line. I want to split it and tag each piece on its centroid. I have a good idea about how I'd tag a contour on its centroid, but not how to get that contour.

[image]

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(path)

contours = get_contours() # this I don't know how to do

def get_centroid(c):
    positions = []
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    return (cx,cy)

centroids = [get_centroid(c) for c in contours]

for ix, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
    cv2.putText(
        img,
        text=str(ix),
        org=centroid,
        fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        fontScale=1,
        color=(0, 0, 0),
        thickness=1,
        lineType=cv2.LINE_AA,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cv2.findContours` for this.
Here is a sample approach

```py
image = cv2.imread(path)
### converting to gray scale
gray_scale=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
### applying blur layer to connect nearby pixels
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_scale,(5,5),0)
### binarising
th1,img_bin=cv2.threshold(blur,150,225,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
### finding contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
### draw all contours
image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

def get_centroid(c):
    positions = []
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    return (cx,cy)

centroids = [get_centroid(c) for c in contours]

for x,y in centroids:
    image = cv2.circle(image, (x,y), radius=3, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)
```

### This is the output we got. The green colour indicates the detected contours, and the blue dot is the centroid.

[image: centroid marking]